# Implement mosquitto jwt authentication with django rest framework server

Tags: python, django, rest, authentication, mosquitto

I have implemented mosquitto jwt authentication using django rest framework jwt as sever. In configuration i see no error, but when i run mosquitto and django i have some error,

Here in django terminal ,

```
"POST /api-token-auth/ HTTP/1.1" 400 79
```

and in mosquitto.conf terminal,

```
1490583684: mosquitto version 1.4.11 (build date 2017-03-08 15:27:51+0700)  starting
1490583684: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1490583684: |-- *** auth-plug: startup
1490583684: |-- ** Configured order: jwt

1490583684: |-- with_tls=false
1490583684: |-- getuser_uri=/api-token-auth/
1490583684: |-- superuser_uri=/superuser
1490583684: |-- aclcheck_uri=/acl
1490583684: |-- getuser_params=(null)
1490583684: |-- superuser_params=(null)
1490583684: |-- aclcheck_paramsi=(null)
1490583684: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1490583684: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1490583749: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
1490583749: |-- mosquitto_auth_unpwd_check(andri)
1490583749: |-- ** checking backend jwt
1490583749: |-- url=http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/
1490583749: |-- data=topic=&acc=-1&clientid=
1490583749: |-- getuser(andri) AUTHENTICATED=0 by none
1490583749: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

Here my mosquitto.conf

```
auth_plugin /etc/mosquitto/auth-plug.so
auth_opt_backends jwt
auth_opt_http_ip 127.0.0.1
auth_opt_http_port 8000
#auth_opt_http_hostname example.org
auth_opt_http_getuser_uri /api-token-auth/
auth_opt_http_superuser_uri /superuser
auth_opt_http_aclcheck_uri /acl
```

Can anyone help me about my error ?